# How do I tell Android to remember which client certificate to use for a given site?

Tags: certificates

I have a site that requires a client certificate in order to allow access.

I've successfully installed a client certificate onto my Android device.

When I access the site from Chrome, I'm prompted with a "Choose certificate" modal popup which lists the installed certificates on my device, asking me to choose which to use.

How can I get Android to remember the chosen certificate so that I'm not prompted each time I attempt to login to the site?

[image: cert selection popup modal]